# Split string and apply locale to every row of Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, string, locale, series

I want to make two transformations to the `amount` column of following df:

```
Address                                         type    amount
0   0x88aDa02f6fCE2F1A833cd9B4999D62a7ebb70367  outflow 250,000 VSO
1   0x88aDa02f6fCE2F1A833cd9B4999D62a7ebb70367  outflow 250,000 VSO
2   0x88aDa02f6fCE2F1A833cd9B4999D62a7ebb70367  outflow 250,000 VSO
```

1. I want to cut the ' VSO' substring from all rows.
2. I want to apply `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_us')` to every row, turning every string into a float following that format.

The current code I have is:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_us')
df_test['amount'].str.split(' VSO')[0]
locale.atof((str(df_test['amount'].values)))
```

Which yields me the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "['250000 VSO' '250000 VSO' '250000 VSO' '33333 VSO' '33333 VSO'\n '10400000 VSO' '170833 VSO' '170833 VSO' '170833 VSO' '170833 VSO'\n
```

Comment: Replace your second line with: `df_test = df.test.assign(amount=df_test['amount'].str.split(' VSO')[0])` - & let us know if it didn't work.

Comment: I get this: ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (797). Even though I replaced your df.test with df_test.

Comment: For which line exactly? In the post, you get the ValueError, because although you calculate your amount column (`df_test['amount'].str.split(' VSO')[0]`), you don't assign it to your dataframe. Your third line uses the original dataframe, not the results of the second line of your code.

Comment: I'm not sure for which line, but a previous solution I was using, when it was a list, instead of a Seeries was: for i in vso_amount:
    vso_amount_new.append(i.split(' VSO')[0])

Comment: I hope the answer provided works for you; it is a useful skill to understand error messages and understsand which line causes the error: it makes it easier to fix the error. I don't know what you use, but the thing which you run your python program in is supposed to tell you which line causes the error, I recommend paying attention to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `apply` after removing the trailing "VSO" with [`rstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html):

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_us')
df["amount"] = df["amount"].str.rstrip(" VSO").apply(locale.atof)

>>> df
                                      Address     type    amount
0  0x88aDa02f6fCE2F1A833cd9B4999D62a7ebb70367  outflow  250000.0
1  0x88aDa02f6fCE2F1A833cd9B4999D62a7ebb70367  outflow  250000.0
2  0x88aDa02f6fCE2F1A833cd9B4999D62a7ebb70367  outflow  250000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that @not_speshal answers the question perfectly.
In the case that the string change slightly (like `VSO` is changed for example), we can use the following `regex` :

```py
>>> df['amount'] = df.amount.str.extract(r"(\d+\,\d+|\d+)")[0].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)
>>> df
    Address                                     type        amount
0   0x88aDa02f6fCE2F1A833cd9B4999D62a7ebb70367  outflow     250000.0
1   0x88aDa02f6fCE2F1A833cd9B4999D62a7ebb70367  outflow     250000.0
2   0x88aDa02f6fCE2F1A833cd9B4999D62a7ebb70367  outflow     250000.0
```